# Ruby automatically add argument when "wrong number of arguments" appears

Tags: ruby, error-handling, argument-error

Hi guys I am doing this [codewar challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/prefill-an-array/train/ruby).

The goal is to implement data structure manipulation for method prefill(n, v).

```
def prefill(n, v)
    some code
end
```

One of the requirements is to give a default **"undefined"** value for the method argument **v** if it's not given when method is called.

I am not sure how I can catch this ArgumentError and re-trigger the iteration of prefill. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to, you need to use [default arguments](https://learn.co/lessons/methods-default-arguments), like this:

```
def prefill(n, v = nil)
  # code
end
```

Comment: This is great! thanks a lot!